# Jenkins Buildflow plugin: how to make variable numbers of jobs in parallel?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Job made with BuildFlow, this jobs receives a parameter like `job1`, `job2`, `job1` `job2`.

In my DSL I separate the value of the parameter with a `split(",")`, so now I have an array with: `["job1","job2","job1 job2"]`.

Now i want to make the DSL run a subjob with X builds in parallel, where X is the size of the array, and iterate to get each position of the array as a paramater to pass to the build of the subjob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this within your dsl:

```
subjob = "yourJobName"
subjobIteration = []

["job1","job2","job1 job2"].each{ parameter ->
  //add the closure to trigger the subjob to the list
  subjobIteration.add({build( subjob, parameter )})
}

parallel( subjobIteration )
```

This snippet uses the Syntax for Parallel job-executions documented [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).

Groovy processes the list `subjobIteration` by default for the "parallel"-DSL correctly, so no further steps are needed.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this? How did you know to do that?

Comment: It is all about Groovy. In the "Build Flow Plugin" documentation you can find the entry for parallel. The list subjobIteration consists of multiple items, that fits the syntax `{ build("yourJobName","job1") },{ build("yourJobName","job2") }` etc. The list is interpreted like that by Groovy.