# Multiple concurrent builds of the same project in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, perforce

On my team, we have a project that we want to do continuous-integration-style testing on. Our build takes around 2 hours and is triggered by the "Poll SCM" trigger (using Perforce as the server), and we have two build nodes.

Currently, if someone checks in a change, one build node will start up pretty much right away, but if another change gets checked in, the other node will not kick in, as it's waiting for the previous job to finish. However, I could like the other build node to start a build with the newer checkin as soon as possible, so that we can maximize the amount of continuous testing that's occurring (so that if e.g. one build fails we know sooner rather than later).

Is there any simple way to configure a Jenkins job (using Poll SCM against a Perforce server) to not block while another instance of the job is already running?

Unfortunately, due to the nature of the project it's not possible to simply break the project up into multiple build jobs that get pipelined across multiple slaves (as much as I'd like to change it to work in this way).

Comment: Have you tried the "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" option in Jenkins configuration?

Comment: @tkosinski I had not, because that didn't sound like what I'm trying to achieve. :) I'll try that out, thanks.

Comment: @tkosinski Okay, reading the docs it sounds like that's exactly what I want. It seems like the option should be called "if *possible*," not "if *necessary*." I was also confused because it appeared to be part of the YouTrack plugin settings for some reason. Feel free to repost that as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: If you have different labels for your slave nodes, then just include them in the section `Restrict where this build runs`. It will pick and choose available executors on any of the nodes. But if both the nodes have the same capability, then give them the same label and add it in this option.

Comment: @Aditya The slaves are all on the same label. The problem was that e.g. build 1572 would wait for build 1571 to finish, even with spare capacity available. tkosinski's answer fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" option in Jenkins configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Just to register here in case someone needs it, in the version I'm using (Jenkins 2.249.3) I had to **uncheck** the option `Do not allow concurrent builds` in the child job that is called multiple times from the parent job.

The code is more or less like that:

```
stage('STAGE IN THE PARENT JOB') {

        def subParallelJobs = [:]
        LIST_OF_PARAMETERS = LIST_OF_PARAMETERS.split(",")

        for (int i = 0; i < LIST_OF_PARAMETERS.size(); i++) {
                
            MY_PARAMETER_VALUE = LIST_OF_PARAMETERS[i].trim()
            MY_KEY_USING_THE_PARAMETER_TO_MAKE_IT_UNIQUE = "JOB_KEY_${MY_PARAMETER_VALUE}"

            def jobParams = [ string(name: 'MY_JOB_PARAMETER', value: MY_PARAMETER_VALUE) ]
            subParallelJobs.put("MY_KEY_USING_THE_PARAMETER_TO_MAKE_IT_UNIQUE", {build (job: "MY_CHILD_JOB", parameters: jobParams)})  
        }

        parallel(subParallelJobs)
    }
}
```