# Using loop to run parallel builds using build-flow plugin in Jenkins

Tags: loops, groovy, jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-build-flow

I am using the build flow plugin to run tasks in parallel in Jenkins. Initially it was this that works:

```
parallel (
    { build("jobX", param: params["inputVal1"])
    },
    {build("jobX",  param: params["inputVal2"])
    }
)
```

However, my need now requires me to write this in some kind of loop since the number of jobs is dynamic. I want to do something like this (conceptually):

```
parallel
(
    for(int i=1; i<=numOfJobs; i++)
    {
        build("jobX", param: params["inputVal" + i])
    }
)
```

There is an answer provided in [Jenkins Buildflow plugin: how to make variable numbers of jobs in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035461/jenkins-buildflow-plugin-how-to-make-variable-numbers-of-jobs-in-parallel), but it does not suit my need exactly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387614/parallel-jobs-using-build-flow-plugin-with-loop-in-jenkins ?

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. I am having trouble writing the Groovy syntax here since I want to loop deterministically based on an integer value but not on a List. Something like this following the answer in the indicated URL above: `parallel numJobs.each { index -> { -> build("jobX", param: params["inputVal" + index]) } }`. But this does not work either. Could you help with the syntax here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need something like:

```
parallel((1..numOfJobs).collect { index ->
    { -> build("job${index}", param: params["inputVal" + index]) }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. I did it with a slight variation, but this works.

Comment: This is actually missing parentheses around the whole expressions… it should be `parallel ((1..numOfJobs).collect { index ->
    { -> build("job${index}", param: params["inputVal" + index]) }
})`